# Storing Java SQL Exception Message

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a Java program where a user sends SQL commands to a database. When there is an SQL exception, such as "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'", this message displays in the terminal, which is fine. However, I want to somehow store this message and display it again in another place in the program but I'm not quite sure how to do this. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
String error;
try
{
    //etc...
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    error=e.getMessage();
}

//somewhere later in code...
System.out.println(error);
```

Whenever I try this, "null" is displayed rather than the message. I thought getMessage() was what I needed for this but apparently it's not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
try
{
    //etc...
}
catch(SQLException e)
{

    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));

}

System.out.println(errors.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. getMessage() should give you correct error message. There will be some other reason why your exception is null

```
try{
  //
   }catch(SQLException e){
      e.getMessage() // will return message like "No suitable driver found for ..."
      e.getErrorCode() // should give you SQL Error code
   }
```

Keep in mind getMessage() not only return SQL errors, it also returns error coming out out java.sql package. For example "No suitable driver found..." is not coming from database in fact it is from java.sql package.

Which database are you connecting to? Can you update the actual code here?